# How can I fix this?? VS Code inserts keycode when moving lines with numeric keypad arrows

Tags: visual-studio-code

VS Code 1.75.1

When moving lines with ALT-UP/DOWN using the dedicated arrow keys, VS Code works as expected.

I have my numeric keypad locked to use the control function rather than as a numeric keypad.

When I move a like with ALT-UP/DOWN using the arrows on the numeric keypad, VS Code moves the line then inserts a character after I release the ALT key.  If anything is selected, VS Code does the move then replaces the selected text with a character.  I'm guessing the character is derived from the keycode of whatever arrow keys on the numeric keypad I pressed.

How can I have VS Code just do the move and not insert characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not VSCode problem, this is keyboard behavior, you can test it in any input field.
Seems the best way is to use some soft (like Autohotkey) to map numpad arrows to main arrows.

Comment: Notepad++ doesn't do it.  I'd call it a shortcoming of VSCode.